# If $\log_a3=p$ and $\log_a2=q$ what strategies deduce an expression for $\log_a(4.5a^2)$?

Tags: logarithms

If $\log_a3=p$ and $\log_a2=q$ what strategies deduce an expression for $\log_a(4.5a^2)$?

I've considered the exponent forms $a^p=3$, $a^q=2$ and $a^x=4.5a^2$ and other qualities of logs such as $\log_aa=1$ but I don't see how to begin with this one.  I've also considered the additive, subtractive and exponent log laws.

Is it possible to go further than merely saying: $$p(4.5q)$$ $$4.5pq$$

Comment: Can you write $4.5a^2$ in terms of $3,2,$ and $a$?

Comment: $4.5 = \frac {3^2}2$.

Comment: Also, I can use log law 3 to say that $2log_a4.5a$... this seems to me to be heading towards some kind of solution.

Comment: @duckegg Careful: the whole expression isn't squared, just the $a,$ so you can't quite do that. Instead I would recommend doing $\log_a 4.5a^2 = \log_a 4.5 + \log_a a^2 = \log_a 4.5 + 2 \log_a a$ to apply this rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a > 0, you can do the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
log_a(4.5a^2) &= log_a(4.5) + log_a(a^2) \\
&= log_a(4.5) + log_a(a^2) \\
&= log_a\left(\frac{3 . 3}{2}\right) + 2.log_a(a) \\
&= log_a(3^2) - log_a(2) + 2 \\
&= 2.log_a(3) - log_a(2) + 2 \\
&= 2p - q + 2 \\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: wow... yes, I see what you did there.  You used all of the techniques the course I am in has covered so far but you did so in a creative way that had not occurred to me.

Comment: Thank you! If you think this answers the question then you may mark it as an accepted answer for posterity.

Comment: Done :). I read your profile and your work sounds interesting by the way.  Let me know about that final script you mentioned, I could use it too haha

Comment: Which final script?

Comment: Your 'About': final paragraph, last sentence.

Comment: Oh, hahahahaha!! Wrote it long time back